# Tool to plot thread context switch

Tags: c++, multithreading, profiling

I'm looking for a tool for performance analysis and debugging that plots threads context switches, and maybe semaphore states, events, ...
I've used tools like that in the embedded world but I'm now looking for the same in the windows or Linux platforms. 
The application I want to profile is a c++ multithreaded application. 
Does anyone has a tool to recommend for this ?

Comment: did you have a look at intel vtune?

Comment: Both you and Hristo mentioned it, so I gave it a try. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux and Solaris the **Oracle Thread Analyzer** from the Oracle Solaris Studio (it also runs on Linux despite its name) can provide a lot of insight into the performance problems of multithreaded applications. Besides Oracle Solaris Studio is *still free*.

**Intel VTune Amplifier XE** (previously called Intel Thread Analyzer) is available on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: I saw other posts mentioning VTune but didn't think it was good at plotting. It's actually quite good. Especially the 'Locks and Waits Analysis'. I used it and got the job done. Thanks for confirming that it's a tool of choice.

Comment: Intel VTune Amplifier XE does not plot context switches (at least I don't see them on the timeline, there's no option to turn it on and the documentation says nothing about this capability). What it does is it *detects* context switches, but it only does that to show more accurate thread execution time. What *is* plotted on the timeline is synchronization ownership flow.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use xperf tool to collect and plot context switches. It's a free tool, which is a part of [Windows Performance Analysis Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc709422). Worked fine for me, see screenshot.
[image: xperf displaying context switches for threads of my app]

Answer (score 0):

Windows Performance Monitor?

[`perfmon.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx)

I think it's standard on most Windows Platforms and provides information on context switches and much much more.

Windows only I'm afraid though.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not the tool you are thinking about, but it is simple, fast and can be useful.

When using GDB, you can type:

```
info threads
```

to see information about threads being run. Next you can switch to the chosen thread and print the backtrace to see, where it was:

```
thread <thread-id>
bt
```

Comment: How can this be used to detect context switch?